# Disable user interaction temporarily during async function in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, async-await

I'd like to disable UI interaction while performing a quick async function (not a network request, much faster: eg getting an item from AsyncStorage). This is to ensure the user cannot tap a 'checkout' button twice in quick succession while the async method is processing.

Typically with native iOS development, for async methods that are too quick enough to justify displaying a 'please wait' modal, I use `UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents` and `endIgnoringInteractionEvents` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623047-beginignoringinteractionevents)

Is there some equivalent in React Native? Thanks.

Comment: did you try pointerEvents='none' on the View?

Comment: @MukeshSoni Thats a great suggestion, however i'd like to cancel tap events for the entire app, not just that one button, to be safe :)

Comment: You can use pointerEvents='none' on the top view. That should prevent all events for anything below. If you are using redux, you can then set a 'saving' or 'whateveryouraredoing' property inside redux state